# Error: ng:area Bad Argument in angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

Here I am trying to insert data from `form` `attendance-form.blade.php` in table attendance on button click using angularJS.

Now the problem when I click button data is not inserted in table instead it gives

> Argument 'AttendanceFormController' is not a function, got undefined.

Below are my form and AttendanceController.js.

In attendance-form.blade.php

```
<div ui-view="attendanceForm">
    <div class="mdl-grid demo-content" ng-controller='AttendanceFormController'>
        <div class="demo-charts mdl-color--white mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-grid">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group label-static is-empty">
                    <h3>Create Attendance</h3>

                    <div class="form-group label-static is-empty">
                        <input type="text" name="user_id" class="signup form-control"
                               id="i2" placeholder="user_id" ng-model="attendance.user_id">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group label-static is-empty">
                        <input type="text" name="in_or_out" class="signup form-control"
                               id="i2" placeholder="in_or_out" ng-model="attendance.in_or_out">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group label-static is-empty">
                        <input type="text" name="comment" class="signup form-control"
                               id="i2" placeholder="comment" ng-model="attendance.comment">
                    </div>

                    <div class="signup form-group label-static is-empty ripple-container signup">
                        <input type="button" value="Create Attendance" class="btn btn-raised btn-primary" ng-click="createattendance()">
                    </div>

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In AttendanceController.js

```
app.controller('AttendanceFormController', function ($scope, AttendanceService) {
    $scope.attendance = {};
    $scope.attendance.user_id;
    $scope.attendance.in_or_out;
    $scope.attendance.comment;
    $scope.loadAttendance = function () {
        $scope.attendance = AttendanceService.get({id:$scope.params.id});
    }
    $scope.createattendance = function () {
        attendance = {user_id:$scope.attendance.user_id,
            in_or_out:$scope.attendance.in_or_out,
            comment:$scope.attendance.comment
        }
        AttendanceService.post(attendance).then(function(response){
            alert('User successfully added in the system.'+'\n'+'Check console.log for response.');
            console.log(response.data);
        });
    }
});
```